# How to pass data between two 'app.post' methods on a server? (node/express)

Tags: express, methods, scope

I have an `express` server that receives a `.post` containing a `json`. I need to use the data from the initial `.post` for a call to a different API.

How to pass data received from one API call and use it in a different API call?

Here is the code, this is part of a chain of API calls with quite a bit more logic, but I have simplified it here for clarity.

Server receives data:

```
app.post("/pay", (req, res) =>{
  const userInput = req.body.userInput
}
```

A different API needs to use `userInput`:

```
app.post("/reply", (req, res) =>{
  console.log(userInput)}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hit multiple functions on the **same** server, just register them as consecutive middleware. The middleware are called in order from left to right. [Use `next()`](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) to call the next handler.

```
app.post('/pay', handler1, handler2....)
```

When doing this, you'll often find it's useful to extract your handlers (often called controllers) so that they can be unit tested and called elsewhere:

**example controller:**

```
const makePayment = (req, res, next) => {
  // handler logic
}

const createUser = (req, res, next) => {
  // handler logic
}

module.exports = {
  makePayment,
  createUser
}
```

**Router:**

```
import Controllers from '<path to controllers>'
app.post('/pay', Controllers.makePayment, Controllers.createUser)
```

This will work so long as they can execute serially. If the functionalities depend on each other (such as requiring the result from another), you can extract those functionalities and call them directly:

```
import { myMethod } from <path to method>
app.post('/post', (req, res, next) => {
  myMethod(req.body.userInput)
})
```

If you are calling an API from a **different** server, then within your request handler you can use your http client of choice to send a request from your server to their endpoint.

Here's an example using [`axios`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios):

```
app.post('/pay', async (req, res, next) => {
  const data = await axios.post('their_endpoint', {
    data: req.body.userInput
  })

  // rest of handler
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I can understand the concept. A quick followup if you don't mind.. I have three handlers, post1>>get1>>post2. When post1 is hit, it makes a call to PayPal, which then hits get1. post2 should only activate if get1 is successfully called. Do you think this will work with the Controller logic that you suggested?

Comment: Actually, I think I can do this by having a "flag" variable that is set to `true` when the .get method is called. Thanks again, will for sure accept once I get it working :)

Comment: You can also check the status of the GET. In an example using `axios` where the request is made to a variable `res`, I'd do something like if (res.status === 200) { ...} else { ... }

Comment: I can see that this answers the question that I asked, unfortunately, I don't think it will work with my specific use case.